# Why is it optimal to hit with a high total against a high card?

Tags: blackjack

Blackjack charts of optimal play tell me that if I have 16, the dealer shows 10, and I can't surrender, I should hit. But my intuition tells me I should stand. Eight of the fifteen card values I could be dealt, just over half, will cause me to bust. If I stand, I at least have a chance of the dealer busting. But I haven't done any math about this so I'm sure I'm off.

Comment: Small point, it's 8/13 cards that cause you to bust, which is closer to 2/3 than 1/2

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for? "Do the math, you'll see it's optimal" is the obvious answer, but it's obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an intuitive justificatiin:

There's a card on top of the deck. If you don’t draw it, the dealer will.*  If that card is a 7-K and you draw it, you bust. But critically, if you *don't* draw it, the dealer will draw it and win.

If you draw an A-5, your chances of winning improve. The only value that actually has a negative effect on your chances of winning if you draw it is a 6, which causes you to bust but doesn't hand a win to the dealer if you don't take it.

So the question is actually "which is greater: the amount by which an A-5 improves your odds, or the odds of drawing a 6 rather than an A-5?" Suddenly the odds don't seem that outlandish!

*Even if there are other players at the table, statistically it works out the same.

Comment: Does this work if the dealer is showing a 10 and hiding something else? 'Cause everyone starts with 2 cards, including the dealer.

Comment: @JonTheMon as long as two cards have the same information known about them, statistically you can treat them as the same card.

Comment: Now, if you're playing a version of blackjack where the dealer immediately reveals a blackjack in their hole card you would know in this case that the hole card isn't an Ace, and you couldn't treat them identically.  But that will only change the underlying statistics slightly, and drawing a card still puts you ahead

Comment: I'm confused about your point. The card I might/not get is not the same card that is face down by the dealer's 10. So aren't they 2 independent events?

Comment: @JonTheMon Think of it this way.  Imagine the dealer had a choice after you refused a card - they can either take their hole card (which they have not looked at in this scenario), or they can switch it with the card you just refused.  Which should they do?  It doesn't matter, because statistically the cards are identical, because exactly the same info is known about each.  Since statistically the two cards are the same, you can analyze the situation as if they drew your card and get the same result as if they drew their hole card.

Answer (score 1):

Because the dealer shows a 10 he has very low chances to go bust himself and any time that he is not getting busted he wins your 16.